# How to get the XML element that can only contain value?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I'm making a small program that supposedly get all XML elements that can only contain a value. For example *(please refer to the image below),* `<Products>` though it is an element, but it should not be displayed because it just encloses all other elements that can contain value, same for `<Description>` *(the highlighted one, sorry for my english, but hope you get me guys..)*

From the image below, my program should only pick the following elements:

```
<Material_Number>
```

`<Description>` *(the 2 elements but not including the highlighted one)*

```
<Language>  
<Material_Type>  
<Base_Unit>
```

What I actually get is nothing...

[image]

Kindly review my code and advise:

```
public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            XmlNode xmlnode;

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\text.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            xmldoc.Load(fs);

            xmlnode = xmldoc.ChildNodes[1];
            GetElements(xmlnode);                       
        }

        void GetElements(XmlNode inXmlNode)
        {
            XmlNode xNode;
            XmlNodeList nodeList;

            int i = 0;

            if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
            {
                nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;

                for (i = 0; i <= nodeList.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
                    string ss = xNode.Name;
                    GetElements(xNode);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(inXmlNode.Name); 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shorten your code a little but you should start calling to start at the first element.

```
  GetElements(xmldoc.ChildNodes[0]);
```

```csh
    void GetElements(XmlNode inXmlNode)
    {
        if(inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in inXmlNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                GetElements(childNode);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(inXmlNode.ParentNode.Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Batuu, your code works for me but with some tweaks. I used `inXmlNode.ParentNode.Name` instead. Please change your answer then I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi yonan2236, edited. Additionally maybe it would be better practice to return a list<string> in your method, to keep it only responsible for getting the names. Fill your listbox outside the GetElements-Method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your question is not quite clear, as you are speaking about nodes that **can** only contain a value. As it is not possible to know what a given node can or cannot contain without knowing the underlying schema, I will assume that you actually mean nodes that **do** only contain a value.
2. The text value in your (w.l.o.g.) `<Language>` elements is a text node. Therefore, `inXmlNode.HasChildNodes` evaluates to `true` for these nodes, too. You will have to check whether any of the child nodes has its [`NodeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.nodetype.aspx) property set to `XmlNodeType.Element` and if so, skip that element.

Note that the selected response works only in specific cases. As soon as your Xml document contains something like `<Language><x/></Language>`, the `<Language>` element will appear in the listbox even though it does not have a text content. If the Xml document contains `<Language><x/><y/><z/></Language>`, `<Language>` will appear in the result set even three times.